# Cisco Switch Routing performance monitoring

Tags: cisco, routing, switch, ip-routing

It is quite a question for me: I have Cisco Catalyst 2960S switch which is nice hardware even despite its age and EOL. I'd like to set it as small router between several networks within a remote building. Static routes, nothing more.

What I completely miss is its routing performance numbers, and if there any way I can use to predict its congestion during its work.

All the datasheets show me forwarding rates, and yet I can't find anything on how many bytes/packets it can **route** per seconds. I do understand *routing* is not the primary use of the *switch*, but since we do own this switch already, this comes at no extra cost which is good for this very application.

I can also monitor device's CPU usage via SNMP. This tells me some number (up to 100) of how many CPU cycles are used, but I'm not sure what's the target number I should afraid of as I'll load the routing: if the routing is pure made by CPU, and 100% busy of CPU results in switch offline?